# Counting the number of rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something very basic but can't quite figure this one out. I'm using PHP and MySQLi (OOP) rather than MySQL. I could use multiple single select statements then put the count from each number into a variable, but I think it's inefficient.

Okay, there are a few tables;

```
TABLE NAME: UCC_STAFF
id
email
username
password
status

TABLE NAME: UCC_TEMP_STAFF
id
email
username
password
status

TABLE NAME: UCC_TEMP_STUDENTS
id
email
username
password
status

TABLE NAME: UCC_VISITORS
id
email
username
password
status
```

What I'm trying to do is count the number of rows from each table, each row represents a user. As I've explained; It's easy enough to do with one table but I'd like to combine results with a single request into a an array rather than multiple statements into multiple variables.

An example of the desired result would be;

```
$a = results('UCC_STAFF' => '35',
            'UCC_TEMP_STAFF' => '12',
            'UCC_STUDENTS' => '543',
            'UCC_VISITORS'  => '6',);
```

What I would imagine this to look like would be;

```
$db_host = "dbhost";
$db_username = "username"; 
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "dbname";

$mysqli = new mysqli("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT * FROM UCC_STAFF;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM UCC_TEMP_STAFF;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM UCC_STUDENTS;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM UCC_VISITORS";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {

// Results into $results
// How do I do this, what goes here?    

    }

// Print Array
print_r ($results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you looking for something like this with `UNION`

```
 $query  =(  (SELECT CONCAT('UCC_STAFF', '')as UCC_STAFF ,count(*)as count from UCC_STAFF )

              UNION ALL
              (SELECT CONCAT('UCC_TEMP_STAFF', '')as UCC_TEMP_STAFF ,count(*) from UCC_TEMP_STAFF )

              UNION ALL
              (SELECT CONCAT('UCC_TEMP_STUDENTS', '')as UCC_TEMP_STUDENTS ,count(*) from  UCC_TEMP_STUDENTS )

              UNION ALL
              (SELECT CONCAT('UCC_VISITORS', '')as UCC_VISITORS ,count(*) from UCC_VISITORS ) );
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d4e3/4)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that to count data from multiple tables with one query.

```
$query  = "SELECT ";
$query .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UCC_STAFF) AS count_staff, ";
$query .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UCC_TEMP_STAFF) AS count_temp_staff, ";
$query .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UCC_TEMP_STUDENTS) AS count_students, ";
$query .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UCC_VISITORS) AS count_visitors";
```

Answer (score 1):

Create **one** table

```
TABLE NAME: UCC_PEOPLE
id
email
username
password
status
type <-- use this field to distinguish different types
```

Run **one** query to get the **count** of records, not records themselves

```
SELECT type, count(*) cnt, FROM UCC_PEOPLE GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it is quite sensible however it's just a scenario, I'm still learning and what I'd like to know is how to count the rows from different tables and put those results into an array.